# And it goes around

Tags: riddle

A short riddle.  It has been through the [Sandbox](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5276/the-riddle-sandbox/5305?noredirect=1#comment11630_5305).

```
My adventurous owners keep one on the ground
But two is more common, most people have found
Three is the usual for those young of heart
And four is for those learning the part
I have a cousin who uses one more
Though one of them is not like the other four
```

What am I?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sounds like a

> bicycle wheel

My adventurous owners keep one on the ground

> Wheelie!
>
>  [image]

But two is more common, most people have found

> Standard way of riding is with two wheels on the ground

Three is the usual for those young of heart

> Tricycles for the kids!

And four is for those learning the part

> A bicycle with training wheels.
>
>  [image]

I have a cousin who uses one more
Though one of them is not like the other four

> Hmm....this thing?!
>
>  [image]

or, more probably

> Your cousin is a car (another common mode of transportation) and the 5th wheel is the steering wheel (thanks, @Neon612!).

What the OP intended before seeing the other 5-wheeled bike above:

> [image]

Title: **And it goes around**

> They sure do.

Comment: I think the one wheel is more likely a unicycle since the rest are all related to how many wheels are attached to the bike.

Comment: 5th wheel could be a steering wheel

Comment: @EngineerToast, Neon612 Googling 5-wheel vehicles is kind of fun.

Comment: holy crap, I've never seen that 5-wheeled contraption before, but I think I want one. <realizing I'm old> - nah, I can live without it.

Comment: Very good.  I added in what I intended for the 5-wheeled vehicle, which is cycle related.

Comment: @APrough Thanks. Just an amazing series of things like [this](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/GXEju7OG0wA/hqdefault.jpg) out there.

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> Points of contact

Reminds me of

> the Sphinx riddle

My adventurous owners keep one on the ground

> a snowboard or something?  Or a reference to running where you're only touching the ground with one foot at a time.

But two is more common, most people have found

> humans tend to use two feet

Three is the usual for those young of heart

> walking sticks are for old people

And four is for those learning the part

> crawling

I have a cousin who uses one more
Though one of them is not like the other four

> a dirty joke?! O.o - or, more likely (as pointed out by beastly gerbil) a monkey "cousin" with a tail.

Comment: The last one I think is monkey with a tail

Comment: Just realised I read usual as unusual :(  ah well :)

Comment: @BrentHackers Those old of body may still be young of heart. It could just refer to being more active in age.

Answer (score 1):

I mentioned this in the Sandbox:

> Feet

My adventurous owners keep one on the ground

> hop, hop, hop

But two is more common, most people have found

> Yeah.

Three is the usual for those young of heart

> Right foot, left foot, and a hand :P/This could refer to hight, three feet tall

And four is for those learning the part

> babies crawling around on arms/legs

I have a cousin who uses one more
Though one of them is not like the other four

> Monkeys - Four legs and a tail. *(Thanks, @BeastlyGerbil!)*

Comment: Like the points of contact one, I think the cousin with the fifth is monkey with a tail